# How to check is Navbar Collapse element is collapsed or not in CSS, Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a Navbar element with nav-items that collapses when clicked. I'm trying to adjust the width of the collapsable nav-item in CSS, using the .collapse class. To do so, I'm trying to check if the .collapse class is collapsed kind of like .collapse:active.

Using the sb-admin bootstrap template, https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/

Comment: Hi Gauthier, welcome to SO. Your question appears to be code specific. Please include the related html and css in your post. This helps others to help you with your issue by seeing what you are working with and some of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

When it's collapsed it won't contain the `show` class, so you can use:

```
.collapse:not(.show) {
 ...
}
```